# Thermodynamic analysis using linear interpolation

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the values of temperatures between 2250 K to 2300 K and have written a basic equation that uses linear interpolation to define the enthalpies between these temperatures. I am not exactly sure how to do this.

This is the equation:

```
T1_e = 868739/(0.9*h1_co2 + 0.1*h1_co + 2*h1_h2o + 0.05*h1_o2 + 7.52*h1_n2)

T2_e = 868739/(0.9*h2_co2 + 0.1*h2_co + 2*h2_h2o + 0.05*h2_o2 + 7.52*h2_n2)
```

The values of `h1_co2`, `h1_co`, `h2_co2`, `h2_co` and so forth are constants for the respective temperatures of K.

`T1_e` represents the temperature at 2250 K.

`T2_e` represents the temperature at 2300 K.

Comment: my guess is you want to use numpy's polyfit. the numpy documentation is excellent. (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your answer would something like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define your constants
h1_co2 = 7
h1_co = 12
h2_co2 = 6
h2_co = .5 
# etc...

def T1_e(h1_co2, h1_co, h1_h2o, h1_o2, h1_n2):
    t1_e = 868739/(0.9*h1_co2 + 0.1*h1_co + 2*h1_h2o + 0.05*h1_o2 + 7.52*h1_n2) 
    return t1_e

def T2_e(h2_co2, h2_co, h2_h2o, h2_o2, h2_n2):
    t2_e = 868739/(0.9*h2_co2 + 0.1*h2_co + 2*h2_h2o + 0.05*h2_o2 + 7.52*h2_n2)
    return t2_e

temp = [2250, 2300]
e1 = T1_e(h1_co2, h1_co, h1_h2o, h1_o2, h1_n2)
e2 = T2_e(h2_co2, h2_co, h2_h2o, h2_o2, h2_n2)
e = [e1, e2]

p = np.polyfit(temp, e, 1)

x = np.linspace(2250, 2300, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.poly1d(x))
plt.show()
```

Comment: that helps quite a bit....thank you! but one other thing.... is there a way to do a simple assertion error for values outside the 2250-2300 range? im not very proficient at assertion errors

Comment: there's 2 ways to handle errors. You can use `if` statements or `try, except` blocks. Using `try`, `except` is generally preferred to handle know errors. Are you trying to limit the range of the linear fit?